# unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, regex

```
def x(self, line):
    match_start_tag = re.search( r'<[^/]*>', line, re.M|re.I)
    match_end_tag = re.search( r'<[/]*>', line, re.M|re.I)
    if match_start_tag & match_end_tag:
       return match_start_tag
    elif match_start_tag & match_end_tag == None:
        return match_start_tag
    elif match_end_tag & match_start_tag == None:
        self.print_ending_bracket(line)
        return -1
```

I am trying to identify if there is an html start tag or end tag in the line and then perform subsequent tasks but I get the error in the title at the first "if" statement.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: probably you need `and` not bitwise `&`

Comment: You might want to explore `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: `r'<[/]*>'` doesn't match what you want it to. It is unlikely that the other regex will match what you want it to either, but the `match_end_tag` regex isn't even close.

Comment: More on HTML parsing with regexes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3318517